# Git Extensions - Can't connect to GitHub, but it's fine using command line

Tags: git, git-extensions

Thank you very much in advance for helping!

I'm trying to pull a local repository to GitHub but for some reason Git Extensions can't connect with it. I've tried everything and I'm completely run out of ideas or places to look for a solution.

This is what I get when I push my repository using Putty (actually Puttycyg):

[image]

This is what I get when I try to push my repository using Git Extensions:

[image]

This is my remotes tab:

[image]

This is what I get when I click on test:

[image]

And finally, more stuff showing what's in my computer and in GitHub:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: it looks to me that you didnt tell git extensions where your key file is? (the "private key file" field in your remotes tab is empty?)

Comment: I've made a private key using puttygen, and added to that field, but it doesn't make any difference at all. 
Also, I can successfully test the connection to GitHub in my laptop without having any private key in that field.

Comment: have you connected to github with PuTTY? it's required

Comment: I have push my repository using Puttycyg (added screenshot in my question). Does it count as 'connect to GitHub with PuTTY?

Answer (score 0):

Check what `%HOME%` looks like in your PowerShell session.

If you want ssh to find your keys, `HOME` should be set to: `C:\Users\rafaelgp\AppData\Roaming`, in order to find the `.ssh` directory in which you have your keys.

Or at least put the full path of the private key in the "PuTTY SSH private key file" field, in the "remote repositories" dialog.